# How to draw a smooth circle with a border in glsl?

Tags: glsl, shader, fragment-shader, blending

I want to draw a smooth circle in GLSL but with a border of variable width, in a separate colour. Potentially, the interior of the circle could be transparent.

My original non-smooth shader:

```
#version 330

layout(location=0) out vec4 frag_colour;

in vec4 color;

uniform float radius;
uniform vec2 position;
uniform vec4 borderColor;
uniform float borderThickness;

void main()
{
    float distanceX = abs(gl_FragCoord.x - position.x);
    float distanceY = abs(gl_FragCoord.y - position.y);

    if(sqrt(distanceX * distanceX + distanceY * distanceY) > radius)
        discard;
    else if(sqrt(distanceX * distanceX + distanceY * distanceY) <= radius &&
            sqrt(distanceX * distanceX + distanceY * distanceY) >= radius-borderThickness)
        frag_colour = borderColor;
    else
        frag_colour = color;
}
```

This works, but is not smooth. I can draw smooth circles:

```
#version 330

layout(location=0) out vec4 frag_colour;

in vec4 color;

uniform float radius;
uniform vec2 position;
uniform vec4 borderColor;
uniform float borderThickness;

void main()
{
    vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy - position;

    float d = sqrt(dot(uv,uv));

    float t = 1.0 - smoothstep(radius-borderThickness,radius, d);

    frag_colour = vec4(color.rgb,color.a*t);
}
```

But I can't work out how to add my border to the above.

Comment: not smooth because no anti-aliasing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to compute the absolut value of the difference between the radius and the distance and interpolate between 0.0 and `borderThickness`:

```c
float t = 1.0 - smoothstep(0.0, borderThickness, abs(radius-d));
```

[image]

If you want to fill the circle, then you need 2 gradients. 1 for the transition between the inner circle and the border and a 2nd one for the alpha channel on the outline. [`mix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/mix.xhtml) the colors by the former and set the alpha channel by the later:

```c
float t1 = 1.0 - smoothstep(radius-borderThickness, radius, d);
float t2 = 1.0 - smoothstep(radius, radius+borderThickness, d);
frag_colour = vec4(mix(color.rgb, baseColor.rgb, t1), t2);
```

[image]